# How to set background color only for half of the tableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to only color my left half or right half of my tableview cell background. How can I manage that? For now, I am only able to set the background color for the entire row. I have tried to put a label on the left half of the cell, and set the background color of the label. But the problem is then the label covered the cell.text so that I cannot see the content of the cell. I really want to know if I can set the label just under the cell text but above the cell's background. so it can does its work. But other approach to accomplish just coloring half of the tableview cell is appreciated as well!

I have tried @winnder.ktw to set it up programmatically. however I got an error [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjR1D.png) how can i fix that??
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using interface builder, just change the order of the views in the Document Outline panel at the left, and you can choose what's on top of what:

[image: Document Outline]

If all you need it the background there's no need to add a label, just add a regular view to your cell.

Edit: here, just add a view and a label, and make sure the label is below the view in the Document Outline panel.

[image]

Comment: To be clear, my question is 'how to change the background color of only left half of the row?'

Comment: Exactly, add a regular view to the left half of your row, then add whatever you want and make sure it's above the view in the Document Outline panel.

Comment: Oh, actually it's the opposite, it has to be below the background view in the Document Outline. I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: thank you , i see what u doing there. I will use view instead of label for the background. But I am using dynamic cell, so I use cell.textLabel.text = xxxx.. to set the content of each cell. so I do not use label. In this case, where I put the view under? so that the view color will not cover the cell text and also the cell has the background color that is equal to the view's color

Comment: Well, you must still be designing that prototype cell somehow, and that `textLabel` is added either in the storyboard or programmatically; where did it come from? You can design the whole prototype cell and add whatever you want to it. Then you subclass `UITableViewCell` and link your view and your label and whatever else to the code.

Comment: can color of cell be changed without adding the view? something like cell.backgroundView.color = newColor

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"any-cell"];
     if (!cell) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier: @"any-cell"];

         UIView* bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: cell.bounds];
         bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
         UIView* halfView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width / 2.0, cell.bounds.size.height)];
         halfView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
         [bgView addSubview: halfView];
         cell.backgroundView = bgView;
     }

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about Objective C, but I understand that you are creating a view programmatically. and to be sure, in your case, how can you set the cell content, and not to be covered by the views you created?

Comment: This code just change backgroundView, so do not cover cell content.

Comment: ok, i think i have some problem with my set up. since it is giving the an error :"terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalid', reason: layer <CALayer:0x7fd75045b9e0> is a part of cycle in its layer tree"